# Testing android:text produces different results depending if it has been modified

Tags: java, android, gettext

I'm experiencing this on my code and I cannot figure out why. Basically I'm setting android:text to "0" on XML and when checking with getText if it's "0" it returns false. If I set it to 0 with setText and check again it returns true.

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:text="0" />

    TextView calc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    return( calc.getText() == "0" ); // false
    ----
    calc.setText( "0" );
    return( calc.getText() == "0" ); // true
```

Why does this happen? How can I check if calc.getText() is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never compare Objects (`String` are a subclass of `CharSequence` which is a subclass of `Object`, and I'd recommend working with them instead of `CharSequence`) with `==`, since that compares references, not actual Object content. All Objects have a `equals()` method, but Strings defintely customize it (override) to implement a check for if the Strings to compare are the same.

Instead do `calc.getText().toString().equals ("0");`

So in terms of why it's happening - Android makes one Object then when you specify "0", you create another one. Using `equals()` solves this because it checks the content first then gives a result (true/false).